# Surfing competitions, no commentators

Tags: surfing

I was just thinking, how great would it be to be able to have a surf spot (live or not live) streamed directly to my PC, with no distracting voice over.

I could have it on my desk while I work, look at the surf, hear the waves and the birds, and it would be like a window on an awesome spot!

Is there a website that offers a variety of recordings of surf competitions or just a variety of webcams with audio?

Comment: mute the sound?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about outdoor activities, it's about watching video.

Comment: I'm voting to leave it open because it is about watching video about outdoor activities.

Comment: @Mapperz He said that he likes the atmosphere of the waves and other sounds of nature. I can clearly understand that.

Comment: @Wills Watching videos about outdoor activities is not an outdoor activity.

Comment: @Shem A bit exaggerating, but is searching online for proper gear off-topic here because it is not an outdoor activity?

Comment: @Wills According to that logic, outdoors.stackexchange.com isn't an outdoor activity, and therefore a paradox. On-Topic questions ask about specific issues with outdoor activities, finding a relaxing video to watch like a virtual window into the outdoors isn't an outdoor activity. This is a question that would be better asked in chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any webcams with audio.

However, here's a couple of YouTube videos that might do the job.

[Surfing on Maui (Honolua?)](https://youtu.be/Sn98Gu41n2U)

[some bodysurfing/boogieboarding](https://youtu.be/jKCyFB5LmPo)

[Relaxing 3 Hour Video of Tropical Beach](https://youtu.be/qREKP9oijWI)

[another one in Big Sur](https://youtu.be/fIlJyZEbrzo)

You might be able to find more. I just did a couple quick YouTube searches using "ocean waves" and "relaxing surfing."